# VBA- Transferring data to another work sheet if a column has certain text and pasting it in a certain cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to filter data and paste it into another sheet to a certain range but it is only posting the latest data row. How do I fix the code so that it selects all the rows with the code word and pastes it into the other sheet.

[image]

This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = "pp" Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy 
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A11:A22")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation what you want this to actually do?

Comment: I want the data to go into another excel sheet based on the code pp, FA... etc. so PP would go into another worksheet in the range of A11:A22 and FA would go into another range, A30:A42

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 as Worksheet: Set ws1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 as Worksheet: Set ws2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")

Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 as Long, i As Long
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "pp" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy 
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

---

Here is a more effecient method using a `For Each` loop and one instance of `Copy/Paste` instead of 1 iteration for every matched cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim TargetRange As Range, TargetCell As Range, CopyRange As Range

Set TargetRange = ws1.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
    If TargetCell = "pp" Then
        If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyRange = TargetCell.Resize(1, 4)
        Else
            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, TargetCell.Resize(1, 4))
        End If
    End If
Next TargetCell

CopyRange.Copy
ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

---

Another method would be to apply a filter for your target value `pp` and then copy/paste visible cells.

Comment: Almost, instead of adding a PP code every time, i want it to select all the PP codes and paste them into a certain range in another work sheet say A11:A22

Comment: What isn't working? Please elaborate on the issue with the code. You are giving a set range of 10. What if you have 20 PP codes?

Comment: The code is adding PP as it is written into the table. Say I Have 5 rows of PP in the table, it will only add the last row into Sheet5 instead of adding all 5 rows of PP into sheet 5